# Qt QFile return non existent but still opens and writes to file

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I have this file which is located in my C drive, I know it exists. When I access it with QFile.exists() it returns false, however it still opens the file and writes to it, I just cant read it. I've been working on this for a while and cannot find a solution, any suggestions are appreciated.

```
QFile tmpfile("C:/file.txt");
    QString tmpcontent;
    if(!QFile::exists("C:/file.txt"))
        qDebug() << "File not found"; // This is outputted
    if (tmpfile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate)) {
        QTextStream stream(&tmpfile);
        stream << "test"; //this is written
        tmpcontent = tmpfile.readAll(); // this returns nothing
    }
```

Comment: Mabe the `exists` function doesn't handle forward slashes, while the `open` function just passes the path down to the system. Perhaps.

Comment: Have you checked the [permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx) of the file itself? Possibly, you have only write permission. This would explain at least the readAll part, but if Qt checks existence via trying to read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If file is not exist it will be created by open because you do it in write mode.

`readAll` function return all remaining data from device, since you just write something you are currently at the end of a file, and there is no data, try to `seek( 0 )` to return to the beginnig of a file and then use `readAll`.

```
qDebug() << "File exists: " << QFile::exists("text.txt");
QFile test( "text.txt" );
if ( test.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate ) ){
    QTextStream str( &test );
    str << "Test string";
    qDebug() << str.readAll();
    str.seek( 0 );
    qDebug() << str.readAll();
    test.close();
}else{
    qDebug() << "Fail to open file";
}
```

As I can see from your code you need that file as a temporary, in such case I suggest to use [QTemporaryFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtemporaryfile.html#details), it will be created in temp directory (I belive there will be no problem with permissions), with unique name and will be auto deleted in object dtor.